# Make matchit.vim work with erb files?

Tags: ruby, vim

Matchit.vim currently works with html files.

However when I open up an erb file, it matches `<` with `>`, rather than with the matching end tag, even when the cursor is in the middle of the tag word.

I don't care much about matching specific erb tags, but I would like the normal matching of html tags to work when I'm editing erb files.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: if you set the filetype to html (i.e. `:set filetype=html`), does it behave how you expect?

Comment: No.  However, if I change the file extension to html and re-open the file, then it does.

Comment: it works fine for me here, `if` matches with `else` and then `end`. Also the html tag matching works. Perhaps you didn't update the plugin?